# latex: knitr code chunk produces empty line, invalid latex

Tags: r, latex, knitr

When knitting R code inside latex/noweb document that outputs results 'asis', knitr adds an empty line at the end of the output, given the output ends with a newline.  This produces invalid latex code under certain circumstances.  For instance the following document fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
<<echo=FALSE, results="asis">>=
cat("E=mc^2\n")
@
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

while it works if I remove the newline from `cat`:

```
cat("E=mc^2")
```

Is there a way to force knitr not to add newline at the end of asis output?  I can easily remove it from the example above, but when using other functions, such as `print.xtable`, the process of capturing output and manually removing the the final line break feels too hacky...

Comment: Apparently: "known" and "won't fix". https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1085 (this may make you the second person in 3+ years to identify this bug).

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the issues and there were somewhat related ones, but did not notice that one.